# How to force Word for Mac (15.26) to read add-in manifest XML?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365, office-js

After updating Office to 15.26 performing "right click on task pane add-in" -> "Reload" brings cached add-in version.

Changing add-in manifest XML (either add-in version or anything else) have no effect at all for a long time period.

Manifest resides in `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents/wef` folder.

Is there a way to **force Word for Mac to read manifest** instantly and update referenced JS task pane add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force a refresh of an add-in (the HTML/CSS/JS) on a Mac, clear the **/Users//Library/Containers/com.Microsoft.OsfWebHost/Data/** folder.

Comment: Indeed! You made my day :) It does help to force add-in reload (no Word restart needed). Also it may be helpful for someone to setup hosting response headers to not cache, at least while developing. See my comment to Juan Balmori answer:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636767/how-to-force-word-for-mac-15-26-to-read-add-in-manifest-xml/39650255?noredirect=1#comment66783407_39650255

Comment: UPDATE ON THIS ISSUE: The cache on a Mac is now automatically refreshed when the add-in is reloaded. There are still some rare situations in which you may need to manually clear the cache: For more info, see https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac#clearing-the-office-applications-cache-on-a-mac-or-ipad

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but  I think what you are expecting to happen is to be able to replace the manifest while Word is running and expecting changes without restarting word?
if that's the case that's not possible, you need to close Word and restart it.

hope this helps.
thanks!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, Juan. What I do really want to achieve is simply reload add-in within Word task pane while developing to check if changes in sources have desired effect.

At this time it looks like Word not picking up updated add-in sources, but using cached version. For some time period, which exactly I'm unable to determine. Moreover, restarting Word doesn't help neither pick up updated manifest nor updated add-in sources, which leads to state when add-in debugging simply impossible on Mac.

Comment: There is a thread related to my case: [Word 2016 javascript add in doesn't refresh](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abce89a7-3b28-4c8b-bdc8-8e07152a0269/word-2016-javascript-add-in-doesnt-refresh?forum=worddev). It is said in accepted answer that _Word 2016 might not check for changes every single time_. How often does Word check for changes? How to force Word to get updated manifest and, what is more important, get updated web app sources?

Comment: you should not be changing your manifest to load the latest page. what's going on is that your HTML is been cached by the Webkit.  have you added tags on your html to avoid caching? something along the lines of  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

Comment: Good point! It turned out that my hosting service (Firebase) adds cache-control:max-age=3600 (that is 1 hour) response header by default. And it is important to know that when an HTML page is served, and a header is present in both the HTTP response headers and the HTML <meta http-equiv> tags, then the one specified in the HTTP response header will get precedence over the HTML meta tag. So I had to simply specify max-age=0 in my hosting configuration.

Comment: Don't you believe that Word for Mac "Reload" context menu item and "Reload" (i) hover button invoked menu item should better trigger "force reload" in order to clear cache memory? The same way as it works in Word for Windows? What is funny - if you have your hosting response set to very long period, there will be no way to get updated add-in sources even after hosting response header has changed (even restarting Word doesn't help). So it looks like one will have to wait for time period specified previously in response header. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: yes this is a known issue for us, we are working on a capability that will force refresh upon reload on Mac.

Comment: UPDATE ON THIS ISSUE: The cache on a Mac is now automatically refreshed when the add-in is reloaded. There are still some rare situations in which you may need to manually clear the cache: For more info, see https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac#clearing-the-office-applications-cache-on-a-mac-or-ipad